# Which value query function return in case of a failure?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm using [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) with PHP and I want to know if my query failed or not.

Does query return FALSE in a case of a failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual on [sqllite_query](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php):

> This function will return a result handle or FALSE on failure. For queries that return rows, the result handle can then be used with functions such as sqlite_fetch_array() and sqlite_seek().
>
> Regardless of the query type, this function will return FALSE if the query failed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a true failure - throw an exception.

If you expect the failure - returning `null` is what's done usually.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`sqlite_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php) says:

> This function will return a result handle or FALSE on failure.